# residue integral $\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{(x^2+1)\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Mathews and Walker (pg 73) give the residue integral example $\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{(x^2+1)\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. I follow the entire calculation until the last step, where the residue at both $\pm i$ is simply stated to be $\frac1{2i\sqrt{2}}$, whereas I would say the residue at $-i$ is $-\frac1{2i\sqrt{2}}$.  Clearly the book is correct. But where does that sign come from?  [It's either really obvious, or buried in a branch choice somewhere; but I'm not finding it.]

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  All I needed to do was to stop thinking about it -- and the resolution hit me in the shower.  Above the cut the phases of $(1\pm x)$ are zero, but below the cut (where the second pole resides) $\arg(1+x)=0$ whereas $\arg(1-x)=2\pi$ (at least on the principal branch).

Answer (score 0):

if $f(z) = \frac{\phi(z)}{(z-z_0)}$ where $\phi(z)$ is analytic and non-zero at $z_0$, then the Residue at $z=z_0$ is $\phi(z_0)$. With that in mind, 
$ \phi(z) = \frac{1}{(x-i)\sqrt{1-x^2}}, z_0 = -i$, so the residue is $-\frac{1}{2i\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: But this is my point:  I also get $-\frac1{2i\sqrt{2}}$; the book does not

Comment: It must have something to do with the cut along the real axis between $\pm 1$.